# How do I compare two lists where one list starts with the other, and only return the "overhang" elements?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two `List<string>`:

List 1:

```
snap
crackle
```

List 2:

```
snap
crackle
pop
bang
```

List 2 will *always* start with the same elements as List 1, but will *always* have some extra elements "hanging off the end."  I want to return a list of just these "overhang elements."

So in the above example, I want a list of:

```
pop
bang
```

Is there a LINQ operator that does this?

Comment: If one list will _always_ start with the contents of the second, why don't you just get the range at the end? Linq not required. `list2.GetRange(list1.Count, list2.Count - list1.Count)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Except extension method:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "snap", "crackle" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "snap", "crackle", "pop", "bang" };
var result = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

Ivan Stoev pointed that the solution above will produce the set difference. If you want the list difference and the second list always contains elements from the first list at the beginning you can use this solution:

```
var result = list2.Skip(list1.Count).ToList();
```

Run this example on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u2MTpZ).

Comment: `Except` *Produces the **set** difference of two sequences*, not the **list** difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) linq method to do this:

```
var onlyIn2 = list2.Except(list1);
```

Comment: `Except` *Produces the **set** difference of two sequences*, not the **list** difference.